# ToElementMesh with OpenCascadeShape returns incomplete region

Tags: numerics, regions, mesh, opencascade

I am solving a PDE using the NDSolve over a cylinder (length L=0.03 m and radius r=0.0025 m). I define the cylinder using OpeCascadeLink and the mesh as shown below. The problem is, the output of the ElementMesh shows that the y-range is smaller than defined (0.00248 instead of 0.0025). I tried with a finer mesh (MaxCellMeasure) but the result didn't change. I tried DiscretizeRegion, but it gives an error. What causes this and how to fix it? Thanks!

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"]
L = 0.03; r = 0.0025;
OpenCascadeShapeType[cyl];
cyl = OpenCascadeShape[c1 = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {L, 0, 0}}, r]];
bmesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[cyl];
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh] (*returns smaller range for y*)
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, "MaxCellMeasure" -> 10^-12,"MeshOrder" -> 2] (*returns same smaller range for y*)
DiscretizeRegion[cyl];(*returns error*)
```

The output is

```
   0.0025}}, {TetrahedronElement["<" 12735 ">"]}] 
ElementMesh[{{0., 0.03}, **{-0.00248177, 0.00248177}**, {-0.0025, 
   0.0025}}, {TetrahedronElement["<" 1101146 ">"]}]
DiscretizeRegion::regp: A correctly specified region expected at position 1 of DiscretizeRegion[OpenCascadeShapeExpression[13]]
```

The solution of the PDE is of course over the same incomplete domain.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Clear[bmesh];
bmesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[cyl, 
  "ShapeSurfaceMeshOptions" -> {"AngularDeflection" -> 0.05}]
```

> `ElementMesh[{{0., 0.03}, {-0.0025, 0.0025}, {-0.0025,  0.0025}}, Automatic]`

Or

```
Clear[bmesh];
bmesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[cyl, 
  "ShapeSurfaceMeshOptions" -> {"LinearDeflection" -> 10^-5}]
```

> `ElementMesh[{{0., 0.03}, {-0.0025, 0.0025}, {-0.0025,  0.0025}}, Automatic]`

```
bmesh // BoundaryMeshRegion
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This works well.